# How to write test with many "and" or "or" at the same level?

Tags: bash

It seems that bash test doesn't support logical tests with multiple arguments:

```
[ expr1 -o expr2 -o expr3 -o expr4 ]
```

nor

```
[[ expr1 || expr3 || expr3 || expr4 ]]
```

The same for '-a' and '&&'.
How to write such contition in neat way without too many nested braces
(esp. when there is even more parts in condition) ?

Comment: Can you give some example that doesn't work? Which Bash are you using? It works for me.

Comment: Both of those should work fine; the only thing `bash` doesn't support is `-o` or `-a` inside `[[ ... ]]`

Comment: Note that `-o` is considered obsolete; use `[ expr1 ] || [ expr2 ]` instead, but prefer `[[ expr1 || expr2 ]]` where supported.

Comment: This would greatly benefit from a [mcve] showing the exact command you were trying to run and exactly how it failed.

Answer (score 3):

> It seems that bash test doesn't support logical tests with multiple
>   arguments

It does:

```
$ [ 0 -le 1 -a 1 -le 2 ] && echo yes
yes
$ [[ 0 -le 1 && 1 -le 2 ]] && echo yes
yes
$ [ 0 -ge 1 -o 1 -ge 2 ] || echo no
no
$ [[ 0 -ge 1 || 1 -ge 2 ]] || echo no
no
```

But the `test` man page notes:

> NOTE: Binary -a and -o are inherently ambiguous. Use 'test EXPR1 &&
>   test EXPR2' or 'test  EXPR1  ||  test  EXPR2' instead.

If your question was more about precedence of the operators, note that `&&` and `||` bash list operators have the same precedence and left associativity. It is thus sometimes necessary to group sub-expressions:

```
{ [[ expr1 ]] && [[ expr2 ]]; } || { [[ expr3 ]] || [[ expr4 ]]; }
```

but it is quite simple and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The following examples works for me in Bash 4, e.g.

```
$ [ 1 = 1 -a 2 = 2 -a 3 = 3 -a 4 = 4 ] && echo True || echo False
True
$ [ 1 = 1 -a 2 = 2 -a 3 = 3 -a 4 = 0 ] && echo True || echo False
False
$ [ 1 = 1 -o 2 = 2 -o 3 = 3 -o 4 = 4 ] && echo True || echo False
True
$ [ 1 = 1 -o 2 = 0 -o 3 = 0 -o 4 = 0 ] && echo True || echo False
True
$ [ 1 = 0 -o 2 = 0 -o 3 = 0 -o 4 = 0 ] && echo True || echo False
False
```

As per `man [` (or `man test`):

> Both sides are always evaluated in `-a` and `-o`.
>
> To avoid this, write: `[ -z abc ] && [ -w file ]`.

Comment: This syntax *works*, but is also flagged obsolescent in the [POSIX `test` standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) and not encouraged for new development.

Comment: To expand on that: When `-a` and `-o` are in use, `(` and `)` also need to be supported for grouping, which leads to corner cases trying to disambiguate between `(` as a string being tested and `(` as an operator. For instance, should `[ '(' = ')' ]` be treated as a comparison between `(` and `)`, or it should be treated as `[ -n = ]`, with grouping? This kind of ambiguity leads to mutually incompatible shells; doing your logical operations *outside* of `test` proper avoids it.